# import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig - Cannot resolve symbol 'core'

Tags: java, intellij-idea, wiremock

Keep getting this error on IntelliJ

`Cannot resolve symbol 'core'` for the following import

`import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig`

Not entirely sure why. The following code also shows an error.

Code:

`wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(port));`

Error:

`Cannot resolve method 'wireMockConfig()'`

Stupid check anyone? Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have misconfigured your classpath. Does it have wiremock library on there?

Answer (score 6):

WireMock is distributed in two flavours - a standard JAR containing just WireMock, and a standalone fat JAR containing WireMock plus all its dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/